# Use multiple CodingKeys for a single property

Tags: swift

Is it possible to use multiple CodingKeys for a single property?

```
struct Foo: Decodable {

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case contentIDs = "contentIds" || "Ids" || "IDs" // something like this?
    }

    let contentIDs: [UUID]
}
```

Comment: Why? What is your real goal?

Comment: @matt Trying to parse 2 jsons with the same fields but with different property names

Comment: You mean the JSON key name is dynamic but you know what the possibilities are?

Comment: Yes. There are 3 possible keys for the ids. But the real project is way more complex. I can't just custom decode it. It would be a lot of work. Only my example is that simple and we are talking about 100+ JSON keys for different properties

Comment: This is bad JSON. Don’t use Decodable. Use JSONSerialization and clean up afterwards.

Comment: Its way more complex.. Its not just like this. I only need a answer to my specific question :/

Comment: Okay, then the answer to your specific question is No. But that's silly; this is an x-y question.

Comment: @matt that's bad for me. Thanks for your help tho

Comment: @Jonas just create 3 optional properties and add a computed property to return something like `var contentIDs: String? { contentIds ?? ids ?? iDs }`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do that by using multiple CodingKey enums and custom initializer.
Let me show it by an example

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case name = "prettyName"
}

enum AnotherCodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case name
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let condition = true // or false
    if condition {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    } else {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: AnotherCodingKeys.self)
        name = try values.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the an elegant solution. But what is the condition for? In my case I used the result of container.decodeIfPresent to determine which container to decode from.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply, condition is something generic for your purposes but decodeIfPresent is very good approach one might use it. Also one can try to handle in nested try catch yet I do not recommend that.

Answer (score 6):

Implement the **`init(from:)`** initialiser and add custom parsing as per your requirement, i.e.

```
struct Foo: Decodable {
    let contentIDs: [String]

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey, CaseIterable {
        case contentIds, Ids, IDs
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        if let key = container.allKeys.filter({ CodingKeys.allCases.contains($0) }).first, let ids = try container.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: key) {
            self.contentIDs = ids
        } else {
            self.contentIDs = []
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that this works. Like i said in my question. I was asking for something else. I mean i clarified it in the comments.

Comment: @JonasSchafft I don't think you've specified that anywhere in your question.

Comment: you are right. I specified it in the comments. I'm sorry

Comment: @JonasSchafft Also, I don't see any reason to downvote it if the question doesn't clarify the requirement properly.

Comment: @JonasSchafft Can you show the comment where you can see the `init(from:)` kind of answer? I don't really see that. And about fast, I don't think you should comment on that. You're the one in need of solution here.

Comment: "I can't just custom decode it." is what i wrote and that the actual project is way more complex. And what does being fast has to do with my question? I don't get it

Answer (score 6):

A better and more cleaner solution could be to create an extension on KeyedDecodingContainer which can be reused.

```
    extension KeyedDecodingContainer{
        enum ParsingError:Error{
          case noKeyFound
          /*
            Add other errors here for more use cases
          */
        }

        func decode<T>(_ type:T.Type, forKeys keys:[K]) throws -> T where T:Decodable {
           for key in keys{
             if let val = try? self.decode(type, forKey: key){
               return val
             }
           }
         throw ParsingError.noKeyFound
       }
    }
```

Above function can be used as follows:

```
struct Foo:Decodable{
     let name:String
     let contentIDs: [String]

     enum CodingKeys:String,CodingKey {
         case name
         case contentIds, Ids, IDs
     }

    init(from decoder:Decoder) throws{
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy:CodingKeys.self)
        contentIDs = try container.decode([String].self, forKeys:[.contentIds,.IDs,.Ids])
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    }
}
```

Comment: This helped me out, thank you.  However, the new decode func will throw if the first key isn't present in the JSON.  That isn't a big deal, but if you want to avoid it you can use `if self.contains(key)` before calling `decode()`.

Answer (score 5):

You can't do literally what you're describing, but you can make the process quite mechanical, and you can turn this into autogenerated code using [Sourcery](https://github.com/krzysztofzablocki/Sourcery) if you need that.

First, as usual, you need an `AnyKey` (someday I hope this is added to stdlib; even the Apple docs reference it....)

```
struct AnyKey: CodingKey {
    var stringValue: String
    var intValue: Int?
    init(stringValue: String) {
        self.stringValue = stringValue
    }

    init?(intValue: Int) {
        self.stringValue = String(intValue)
        self.intValue = intValue
    }
}
```

Then you want a new method that can decode from a list of possible keys. This particular implementation tries elements in the dictionary, and then falls back to the name of the key. (This way you don't have to put thing in the dictionary if they only have their own name.)

```
extension KeyedDecodingContainer where K == AnyKey {
    func decode<T>(_ type: T.Type, forMappedKey key: String, in keyMap: [String: [String]]) throws -> T where T : Decodable{

        for key in keyMap[key] ?? [] {
            if let value = try? decode(T.self, forKey: AnyKey(stringValue: key)) { 
                return value
            }
        }

        return try decode(T.self, forKey: AnyKey(stringValue: key))
    }
}
```

And finally, the tedious but simple (and code-generated if you like) init:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let keyMap = [
        "contentIDs": ["contentIds", "Ids", "IDs"],
        "title": ["name"],
    ]

    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: AnyKey.self)

    self.contentIDs = try container.decode([UUID].self, forMappedKey: "contentIDs", in: keyMap)
    self.title = try container.decode(String.self, forMappedKey: "title", in: keyMap)
    self.count = try container.decode(Int.self, forMappedKey: "count", in: keyMap)
}
```

You can make it even tidier with a local function:

```
init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let keyMap = [
        "contentIDs": ["contentIds", "Ids", "IDs"],
        "title": ["name"],
    ]

    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: AnyKey.self)

    func decode<Value>(_ key: String) throws -> Value where Value: Decodable {
        return try container.decode(Value.self, forMappedKey: key, in: keyMap)
    }

    self.contentIDs = try decode("contentIDs")
    self.title = try decode("title")
    self.count = try decode("count")
    // ...
}
```

I don't think you can get much simpler than this using Decodable, however, because you can't decode dynamic types and Swift needs to be certain you initialize all the properties. (These make it very hard to create a `for` loop to do initialization.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you're asking to do. From the question and your later comments, it appears you've got some very bad JSON. Decodable is not made for that sort of thing. Use JSONSerialization and clean up the mess afterward.

Comment: Those are two different JSONs from two different countries with two different languages

Comment: Well my answer stands.